# Django migrate uses wrong database backend for some migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, database-migration

### Summary

Consider a project with two local database configurations, called `'sqlite'` (default) and `'postgresql'`. Running `migrate --database=postgresql` successfully migrates the first few migrations to postgresql, then, suddenly, starts using the wrong database backend, resulting in the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_mymodel
```

### Background

Working on a legacy Django 3.2 project with over ten apps and over two-hundred migrations in total. The project is configured to use PostgreSQL in production, but uses SQLite for *local* testing.

Now, for consistency, I want to configure the project to use PostgreSQL *locally* as well, instead of SQLite.

So, here's what I did:

- created a brand new PostgreSQL database on the local dev system, configured for Django
- added a database configuration called `'postgresql'` to the local settings file, *in addition to* the `'default'` SQLite configuration (see example below)

  ```py
  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
          ...,
      },
      'postgresql': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
          ...,
      },
  }
  ```
- tested and verified the database and corresponding Django configuration
- ran `python manage.py migrate --database=postgresql`

That's where things went wrong.

### Problem

The first hundred migrations (approx.) were applied properly, but then Django ran into an error:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying myapp.0002_copy_data_from_mymodel...python-BaseException
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_mymodel
...
File "/home/dev/Documents/my_project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_mymodel
```

Apparently, for some reason, Django suddenly starts using the `sqlite3` backend, instead of the postgresql backend.

I confirmed that the successful migrations were indeed applied to the postgresql database, using both `python manage.py showmigrations --database=postgresql` and by listing tables in `psql`. The table `myapp_mymodel` does exist in the PostgreSQL database.

I also inspected the offending migration (a custom data-migration) and its dependencies, but did not see anything out of the ordinary there. Other, similar, data-migrations were applied without issue.

### Question

Why does Django suddenly switch to the sqlite database backend, despite using the `--database=postgresql` option, and how do I fix this?

### Research

Perhaps this has something to do with [auto-routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)...

There are also some similar questions, but I could not find a fitting answer there, e.g.:

- [Django project using wrong (old) database settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8772499)

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why Django uses the wrong database engine for the specific migration mentioned in the question, despite using the `--database=postgresql` option.
However, it looks like, for some reason, Django decides to fall back to the *default* database engine, which was configured as sqlite3.

We can work around this issue by setting our `'postgresql'` as the *default* database:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        ...,
    },
    'postgresql': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        ...,
    },
}
DATABASES['default'] = DATABASES['postgresql']
```

Comment: Here's an [issue in an unrelated project](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5846) that does look similar. Although the exact cause is not clarified, they do mention [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) as a solution. This makes sense if you're using multiple databases in parallel, but the use-case above is a bit simpler.